# set default value to null on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) that I should be able to set the default value of a column like this:

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column SET DEFAULT expression
```

But this:

```
ALTER address.IsActive SET DEFAULT NULL
```

Gives me this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "address" LINE 1:  ALTER address.IsActive SET DEFAULT NULL

What have I done wrong? Also, how can I specify multiple columns to have their default value be `NULL`?

Comment: By default values are NULL  no real reason to default it to Null..

Comment: @xQbert seems to be the way phpPgAdmin's working at least.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not running the complete statement. You're missing the `ALTER TABLE` part:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
>     action [, ... ]
> ALTER TABLE [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
>     RENAME [ COLUMN ] column TO new_column
> ALTER TABLE name
>     RENAME TO new_name
> ```
>
> where action is one of:
>   
> [...]

Answer (score 25):

The correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT NULL;
```

For several columns you repeat the `ALTER COLUMN` part as documented in the manual:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
    ALTER COLUMN foo SET DEFAULT NULL,
    ALTER COLUMN bar SET DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. How could you do this for multiple column names?

Comment: @thomas - `action [, ... ]` means you can add as many as you want, separated by commas.

Answer (score 4):

Try like below... it will work....

```
ALTER TABLE address ALTER COLUMN IsActive SET DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table dogs
alter column breed set default 'boxer'

alter table dogs
alter column breed set default null
```